# how to add every value to data object in firebase?

Tags: google-apps-script

Im using this code to push the values from my google sheet to firebase, but i only get the first row added. how can I make this dynamic? everytime there is a new row, there is a new entry created in firebase?

here is the code:

```
//Add in your database secret
var secret = ''

 function getFirebaseUrl(jsonPath) {

return (
'https://gradetracker-789b7-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/' +
jsonPath +
'.json?auth=' +
secret
 )
 }
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var [rows, columns] = [sheet.getLastRow(), 
  sheet.getLastColumn()]
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows, columns).getValues();
 console.log(data);
 var dataObject = {};
 for (var i=1; i <data.length; i++) {
 var dataRow = data[i];
 var uid = dataRow[0];
 var ET1 = dataRow[1];
 var ET2 = dataRow[2];

  dataObject[uid]= {
  et1 : ET1,
  et2 : ET2,
 }

}
```

my sheet data is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SawN.png)

My output right now is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mayuH.png)

but i need this to be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFEEv.png)

Comment: Can you update your script by including the script for accessing to Firebase? And, can you provide the sample input and output situations, that you expect, as the images?

Comment: just updated with the missing parts! any guidance would be appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your additional information, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  // 1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const [[, h1, h2], ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // 2. Create an object for sending to Firestore.
  const obj = data.map(([a, b, c]) => ({[a]: {[h1]: b, [h2]: c}}));

  console.log(obj);

  // 3. Send the object to Firestore.
  // const firestore = ###; // Please set your `firestore`.
  // const res = obj.map(r => firestore.createDocument("###document###", r));
}
```

- When above script is run, `obj` is as follows.

  ```
    [
      {"###uid1###":{"et1":60,"et2":80}},
      {"###uid2###":{"et1":90,"et2":65}}
    ]
  ```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the header (`uid`, `et1` and `et2`) of [your sample spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SawN.png) are the cells "A1", "B1" and "C1", respectively. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)